# How can we integrated ads in video player like YouTube in flutter?

Tags: flutter, youtube, admob, video-streaming, ads

I working with `Flutter` on my video streaming application. I want to implement **ads** in a video player.

How can I implement it?

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: No, Not now. but I believe there might b an alternative way. Instant push ads inside the video player show ads on its above as MX Player did (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en_IN&gl=US&pli=1)